# Insert string with tags in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have such code in views.py

```
template = loader.get_template('mysite/index.html')
context = Context({'try':'<h1>Header no 1</h1>'})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

In index.html I wrote

```
<html>
<body>
   {{ try }}
</body>
</html>
```

And instead header received line tags and all stuff.
How can fix it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "header received line tags and all stuff"?  What does the output look like?  Thanks.

Comment: I meant that instead of big letters, output lookds like < h1>Header no 1</h1>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

template = loader.get_template('mysite/index.html')
context = Context({'try': mark_safe('<h1>Header no 1</h1>')})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```